# Как получить колонки из представления с функцией, возвращающей объектный тип?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Имею представление с функцией:

```
PRIMARY_KEY,
FUNCTION (PARAMETER) AS COLUMN_ONE
--остальной код
```

Сейчас вывод выглядит так:

```
|PRIMARY_KEY|COLUMN_ONE|
|-----------|----------|
|1          |John      |
```

Функция возвращает **только один колонку со скалярного типа** - `COLUMN_ONE`.

Теперь, хочу использовать функцию, которая возвращает **объектный тип**, который имеет несколько атрибутов, чтобы получить несколько колонок, например:

```
|PRIMARY_KEY|COLUMN_ONE|COLUMN_TWO|COLUMN_THREE|
|-----------|----------|----------|------------|
|1          |John      |  Doctor  |123         |
```

То есть, нужны **отдельные колонки**, а не одна колонка со значением объектного типа:

```
|FUNC_RESULT(COLUMN_ONE,COLUMN_TWO,COLUMN_THREE)|
|-----------------------------------------------|
|OBJTYPE('John','Doctor',123)                   |
```

Как можно этого добиться?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Multiple columns in Oracle view by using same function that returns object type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68140229) от участника [@Valkyrie-30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10975861/valkyrie-30)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68140229

Answer (score 2):

Один из простых способов добиться этого - поместить результат функции в коллекцию. При выводе атрибуты элементов коллекции будут представлены отдельными колонками. С этим решением, нет необходимости указывать все атрибуты объектного типа.

Попробуйте следующий [воспроизводимый пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c976f1c22f5d24bdfc94d01045ea9dcd):

```
create table t (id, memo) as
    select 1, 'aaa'  from dual union all
    select 2, 'bbbb' from dual
/
create or replace type o force as object (len int, val varchar2(16))
/
create or replace type coll as table of o
/
create or replace function f (val varchar2) return o is
begin
    return o (length (val), substr (val, 1, 16));
end;
/
create or replace view v as
    select * from t, coll (f(t.memo))  
/
```

Результат:

```
select * from v;

        ID MEMO                    LEN VAL             
---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------------
         1 aaa                       3 aaa             
         2 bbbb                      4 bbbb
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68141430/6571020) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

*Рекомендуемое решение* -- получить отдельные колонки, указав для них явно [атрибуты объектного типа](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Object-Access-Expressions.html#GUID-FA69A056-12A6-420F-A106-EE252386CC43), полученные в результате выполнения функции в подзапросе.

Воспроизводимый [пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=26899b04e275f5d2c7aada5ba5a292a4):

```
create or replace type o force as object (col1 int, col2 varchar2(16))
/
create or replace function f (val varchar2) return o is
begin
    return o (length (val), substr (val, 2, 16));
end;
/
create or replace view v as
    select id, memo, q.r.col1 col1, q.r.col2 col2 
    from (select t.*, f(t.memo) r from t) q
/
```

Запрос и его результат:

```
select * from v;

        ID MEMO       COL1 COL2
---------- ---- ---------- ----------------
         1 aaa           3 aa
         2 bbbb          4 bbb
```